# Converting JSON string to Angular function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular service fetching some JSON data, and in this data I have a function as a string (building it server side and passing it to angular), something like:

```
{
    "fn": "function( data ) { data.rendered = data.value; }"
}
```

Is it possible to parse this and use it as an expression with angular? I.e.

```
settings.myCustomFunction = serviceData.fn;
```

I've attempted to do this with different combinations of `eval`, `$eval`, `$parse`, but I haven't had any luck with any of them. They all either throw errors about "Unexpected *" or don't throw errors, but also don't seem to do anything.

Comment: `new Function()` is the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the string in parentheses to avoid the syntax error.

```
eval("(" + fnString + ")")
```

This makes it a syntactically valid JavaScript statement which is composed of a single function expression that you can pass around freely.

An anonymous function by itself, without any parentheses or LHS operators (like the commonly used assignment operator `=`) acting upon it, is not a syntactically valid JavaScript statement. That's why you'll see IIFEs (immediately invoked function expressions) wrapped up in parentheses in JS:

```
(function() {
  // ...
})()
```

Comment: As much as I wanted this to work, unfortunately I'm getting an "Unexpected token ;" error when trying to use it, with the console pointing right after the `fnString` as the source of the error, so I'm assuming it's talking about the semicolon right after `data.value`.

Comment: @Samsquanch Really? That's strange tbh because it works for me. It's not a syntax error at all unless your function itself has a syntax error in it.

Comment: Copy/pasting from another comment: the function works correctly if use the function directly, i.e. `settings.myCustomFunction = function( data ) { data.rendered = data.value; }`. I agree, it is strange.

Comment: @Samsquanch I think it's your function because `eval` will detect syntax errors in the function itself.

Comment: If that's the case, why would it work fine if I copy/paste the exact function into the code itself?

Comment: @Samsquanch Try copy pasting `var fn = eval("(" + "function( data ) { data.rendered = data.value; }" + ")")` in your browser console. It works fine for me. I believe the problem is in the string you are passing in. It's messed up somehow. Could be the way you're parsing the JSON.

Comment: @Samsquanch  If copy pasting that snippet in my last comment works, then the problem is in your string. If not, then I wonder what kind of JS runtime you're using. Maybe your `window.eval` was overwritten by martians.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. Server side caching was causing your original solution to not work, but after fixing that part your solution is still the only one not throwing an error so I'm going to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get eval to work, then you can do this:

```
var settings = {};
eval("settings.myCustomFunction = " + serviceData.fn);
```

Using eval in this way of course opens your app up to possible malicious script injections.

Comment: This one is returning "data is not defined", but the function works correctly if use the function directly, i.e. `settings.myCustomFunction = function( data ) { data.rendered = data.value; }`.

Comment: As long as you pass `data` in as a parameter when executing it will be defined e.g. `eval("var x = function( data ) { return data + 1; }");
x(1);` works

Answer (score 0):

You could do user [`new Function()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

```
settings.myCustomFunction = new Function('argument',functionbody);
```

To execute:

```
settings.myCustomFunction();//
```

Comment: This one is returning "data is not defined" using `settings.myCustomFunction = new Function(serviceData.fn)`, but the function works correctly if use the function directly, i.e. `settings.myCustomFunction = function( data ) { data.rendered = data.value; }`.

Comment: @Samsquanch, try `settings.myCustomFunction = new Function('data', 'data.rendered = data.value;')`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out `eval.call`. This allows you to not care what the arguments are and use any arguments from strings. Of course to call it you must use the same arguments, BUT, you could string-drive that too, by concatting the args together when you `eval.call` it.

```
{
    "fn": "function( data ) { return data + 1; }"
}
```

Example:

```js
var serviceData = {
  fn: '(function (data) {return data + 1;})'
  };
var data = 44;
var result = window.eval.call(window, serviceData.fn)(data);
console.log(result); // 45
```

Comment: I'm not sure this really works in my use-case. That's more for calling the function immediately, correct? This is a callback function. (I think that's what it's considered anyway, I'm not sure what to call it in JavaScript).

Comment: You execute the call whenever you want. So, maybe I'm missing something, but I think you can. In other words, it doesn't hang around as a function, it lives as a string. then when you want to call it, that's how you call it.